# Add number variables in HTML

Tags: html, variables, numbers

new to site but have been using for a while - its a great help!

I am trying to add two variables from inputs; example 2 + 2 but I keep getting answer 22 not 4.

Once I get around this I will want a form with 5-6 variables and a couple of answers.

Your help please with what I am sure is a very simple answer (I am learning programming).

Here is what I have...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transititonal//EN"
""http://www.w3.org/TR/XHTML1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head></head>
<body>


<form name="profitcalc">

    <table border="1" width="600" height="200" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">

        <tr><th colspan="2">Profit Calculator</th></tr>


        <td>

            Dollar Rate <input type="number" name="xrate" id="input" onchange="calculate();"/>
            <br>
            Marketplace Fee <input type="number" name="marketfee" id="input" onchange="calculate();"/>

        </td>


        <td><input type="number" name="profit" id="output"></td>

    <table>

</form>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function calculate() {

    var vxrate = document.profitcalc.xrate.value;
    var vmarketfee = document.profitcalc.marketfee.value;

    var vanswer = vxrate + vmarketfee;

    document.profitcalc.profit.value = vanswer;

    }

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you read from the `<input>` fields are strings so Javascript concatenates them, hence the `22` result.

You need to force them to numeric values before performing the arithmetic with `parseFloat()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function calculate() {

    var vxrate = parseFloat(document.profitcalc.xrate.value);
    var vmarketfee = parseFloat(document.profitcalc.marketfee.value);

    var vanswer = vxrate + vmarketfee;

    document.profitcalc.profit.value = vanswer;

    }

</script>
```

[Edit]
Revised to use `parseFloat()` rather then `parseInt()` as this code looks like it'll need decimals.